# rstanarm loo: implications of k-pareto values above 1

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, cross-validation

(this is the first time I post here, so please excuse any formatting or other errors)

I have estimated a linear regression model using stan_glm and I am using loo() to evaluate the model fit.

I have read in one of the loo package vignettes (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/loo/vignettes/loo2-example.html#plotting-pareto-k-diagnostics) that Pareto-k values above 0.7 are a sign of bad model specification.

I would like to ask, if it still a considerable problem, given that only 1 of my observations is assigned a k-pareto value over 1. The others are all below 0.5. Should I just rerun the estimation, skipping the 'bad' observation this time?

Below I present the output of loo(stan_model):

```
Computed from 4000 by 45 log-likelihood matrix

         Estimate   SE
elpd_loo    -23.5 19.0
p_loo        11.2  9.2
looic        47.1 37.9
------
Monte Carlo SE of elpd_loo is NA.

Pareto k diagnostic values:
                         Count Pct.    Min. n_eff
(-Inf, 0.5]   (good)     44    97.8%   2210      
 (0.5, 0.7]   (ok)        0     0.0%   <NA>      
   (0.7, 1]   (bad)       0     0.0%   <NA>      
   (1, Inf)   (very bad)  1     2.2%   7    

``
```

Comment: I wouldn't exclude the observation.  I'm not as familiar with the loo package as some, but when this happens we can't be certain of the elpd_loo, so the authors just don't report it (which is why you see NA).  The problem could also be your priors.  Are you using default priors, or do you have principled priors?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have run the model both with default priors and with my own priors for the regressors' coefficients, the result is the same, it's the same observation that yields a high pareto-k value. I am wondering if this error makes my estimated coefficients questionable.

Comment: In my experience, and I will let others correct me if I am wrong, it does not mean the coefficients are questionable.  Do you have so many observations so that an actual leave one out approach is infeasible?

Comment: I just have 45 observations, sorry I had skipped the first line of the output due to a formatting error.

Comment: I think you should actually do a LOO approach instead of using the approximation.